# How to report files with conflicts after merge

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

I use Git for revision control.

I performed the 'git pull' command, some files were successfully merged, but some files ended with the conflicts.

So, how to report files with conflicts after merge in Git?

Answer (score 1):

`git status` should give you the file(s) that have merge conflicts

Comment: Files can - by definition - only be in conflict after you've started a merge. 
 Thus, `git status` will _only_ show you files those files "_after merge_".